# PCSpim Addition Error

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

```
#    PROGRAM TO ADD TWO NUMBERS 
        .text           #directive identifying the start of instructions 
        .globl  __start

__start:

    #print
        la      $a0, prompt     #prompt goes in 
        li      $v0, 4         
        syscall

    #read in integer 
        li      $v0, 5          # service code 
        syscall 
        sw      $v0, Num1       # store what was entered 
    #read another 
        li      $v0, 5          # service code 
        syscall 
        sw      $v0, Num2       # store what was entered

    #do the addition
        lw      $t0, Num1 
        add     $a0, $t0, $v0

    #print the sum
        li      $v0, 1          # print integer service call 
        syscall

    #print a final string line 
        la      $a0, final 
        li      $v0, 4 
        syscall

        li      $v0, 10         # exit program service 
        syscall

    #Data segment 

        .data 
Num1:   .word   0 
Num2:   .word   0 
prompt: .ascii  "Please type 2 integers, end each with the " 
        .asciiz "Enter key:\n" 
final:  .asciiz " is the sum.\n"
```

I am using PCSpim 9.1.9. I tried to reinstall PcSpim but it is still not working.
I am getting error " spim: (parser) syntax error on line 8 of file. 
la $a0, prompt #prompt goes in.

Please Help

Comment: It works for me in PCSpim if I changed the `__start` label to `main`

Comment: does not work for me. getting the exact same error

Comment: I've tried it in PCSpim 8.0 (SPIM 9.1.9) on two different computers, both running Windows 7 64-bit, and it works for me with the change I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Check for cut-and-paste glitches maybe? Like a non-printable character on the problem line. Delete it and retype it manually, perhaps.